# How to retrieve a form POST response on angular 8

Tags: json, angular, forms, post, server

how can I retrieve the server response of the server after making a POST call on a html form?

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/upload" method="POST">
<label for="file">Choose File</label>
    <input type="file"
        id="file"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div *ngIf=badName>
        <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Wrong file format. Only accepted format: csv.</small>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Please read the Angular guide on forms. You clearly haven't done that. https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Answer (score 2):

As a good practice consider using services which sends data to the server and gets response from the server.

Am example from [the Angular docs](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6):

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { MessageService } from './message.service';


@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroService {
    private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
    };

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    /** POST: add a new hero to the server */
    addHero (hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
        return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, this.httpOptions).pipe(
            tap((newHero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${newHero.id}`)),
            catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
        );
    }
}
```

yourcomponent.ts:

```
constructor(private heroService:  HeroService ) {  }

create(){
    this.heroService.addHero( yourObject ).subscribe(resp => {
        console.log(resp)
    }) 
}
```